# How do I inject new tags into a TagLib?

Tags: grails, groovy, metaprogramming

Lets assume that I have the following configuration in my `conf/InjectionConfig.groovy` file:

```
x {
    a = { attrs, body -> out << "hello" }
    b = { attrs, body ->  out << "goodbye" }
}
```

and that I have a simple taglib such as

```
class XTagLib {
    static namespace = "x"
}
```

What I want to do is that when I type `<x:a />` to any of my views, it would print `hello`. I've already tried to inject these to the metaclass of the taglib as both property and method but neither seem to work. As an example, here's basically what I'm doing right now in a service:

```
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    GroovyClassLoader classLoader = new GroovyClassLoader(getClass().classLoader)
    def slurper = new ConfigSlurper(GrailsUtil.environment)
    ConfigObject xConfig
    try {
        xConfig = slurper.parse(classLoader.loadClass('InjectionConfig'))
    }
    catch (e) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    xConfig.x.each({
        if ( !XTagLib.metaClass.hasMetaProperty(it.key) ) {
            XTagLib.metaClass.registerBeanProperty(it.key, { args ->
                def attrs = args[0], body = args[1]
                it.value.call(attrs, body)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Am I just doing it wrong or is this even possible currently?

Comment: I'm afraid ConfigSlurper will execute the code in InjectionConfig when parsing DSL, and result in tree-like values structure only.
What you want is to load closures from the code, but you're getting their execution result, right? Anyway, it's a good idea to log or examine `it.value` under debugger.

Comment: @Victor: Actually no, I'm getting actual closures from slurper; slurper's syntax is a `{ b { c=d } }`, but making `b` a closure (*that is, `{ b={ c=d } }`*) results in a runnable closure.

Comment: Looks like Grails post-processes taglib classes after they're declared. Now I see that you need to do grailsApplication.addArtefact(TagLibArtefactHandler.TYPE, <artifact class>), but yet have to come up with worknig example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this

```
    def shell = new GroovyShell() // or get a GroovyClassLoader
    Class yTagLibClass = shell.evaluate("class YTagLib { static namespace = 'x' }; return YTagLib")

    yTagLibClass.metaClass.a = { attrs, body -> delegate.out << 'blabla' }
    grailsApplication.addArtefact(TagLibArtefactHandler.TYPE, yTagLibClass)
```

<x:a/> nearly worked for me - registered a tag, except for it didn't output anything. You still need to make the closure resolve `out` against Grails' taglib's `out` property.

I don't see a pretty way to do it, as there's no access to instance variables, and `out` is an instance variable. See Grails source, JspInvokeGrailsTagLibTag.doStartTagInternal() - you might find a way.

**EDIT**: I added `delegate.` prefix that should resolve `out` property of target object. Now I believe I deserve an acceptance :)

Answer (score 1):

> What I want to do is that when I type
>    to any of my views, it would
>   print hello

I think there's an alternative way to do what you intend: combine template & tagLib. First, create a template, then add it in your TagLib (with no complex configuration).

In my opinion, it's more simple than your approach.

Please take a look at this tutorial:
http://jan-so.blogspot.com/2008/02/example-of-template-and-taglib-with.html

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't apply to my use case because the actual tags would actually be composed metadata tags. I pretty much have to have the ability to inject new tags on startup.